# jQuery to change all the links in the page

Tags: jquery

```
 $(function(){
            $('a').each(function(){
                        var x=this.href;
                        this.href="www.somesitename.com/filter"+this.href;
                  });
         });
```

i wrote the above jQuery script to append some site name to all the links in the page but it's not working as expected.

Comment: How did you expect it to work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I wonder why would you use jQuery for such basic behaviour...

that is why the [tag BASE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) is there for

> Specify a **default URL** and a **default target** for **all links** on a page:

```
<head>
    <base href="http://www.w3schools.com/images/" />
    <base target="_blank" />
</head>

<body>
    <img src="stickman.gif" />
    <a href="http://www.w3schools.com">W3Schools</a>
</body>
```

don't complicate what is simple!

---

**added**

from [Sitepoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/base)

> The base element is only going to be useful to you if all your **relative links** or **form submissions** go to the same location.

Comment: Is there a way i can do the same to form action element?

Comment: but then  i also want to extract the default base url which was set before writing the base tag .

Comment: $("head > base").attr("href") ??

Comment: According to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp, "there can be at maximum one <base> element in a document ...".
So the answer needs to be modified s.t. href and target are in the same element.

Answer (score 33):

You probably need to add `http://`:

```
$(function(){
    $('a').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('href', 'http://www.somesitename.com/filter' + this.href);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Further improvement of Darin's solution:

```
$(function(){
    $('a').attr('href', (n, old) => 'http://www.somesitename.com/filter' + old);
});
```

One thing to notice that in case of **.each** this.href produces an absolute fully qualified URL (e.g.: *http://localhost:8888/mylink*) so result might look like: *www.somesitename.com/filter/http://localhost:8888/mylink*. The solution was to get attribute value via jQuery: $(this).attr('href'), which correctly yields */mylink*.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is what i have used to do this**

I have removed each 'blog/' from href on the page in the same you can change link or update it

`$('a').each(function(){
       var updated_link = $(this).attr('href').replace('blog/', '');
       $(this).attr('href', updated_link);
    });`

I have used replace function to update part of url.in your case you can update it

Answer (score 0):

define a base tag in your head and then update it's href property when needed.

```
<base href="http://www.some-domain.com/" />
$("base").attr("href","http://www.some-other-domain.com/");
```

Answer (score -2):

You will probably need to use the append() function jQuery has http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: The question is about appending to an **attribute** not an **element**

Comment: yeah i realised the mistake it was supposed to be attribute.