# change all href of external page after insert it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have inserted external content to my page using simple_html_dom.php but all href not working for example :

```
 href='oldpage.php'
```

and I want this like to be changed to

```
href='http://localhost/oldpage.php'
```

or

```
href='http://localhost/mynewpage.php'
```

is there a way to change all href to new one like add some string before it ?
Thank you

Comment: so, why not take care of it during the same time you executed the other script? sounds to me like it would be simpler.

Comment: In case of the first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543196/jquery-to-change-all-the-links-in-the-page

Comment: @Fred-ii- the script can bring all the html text . I want to update all href to new link like add additional text in-front of it !

Comment: All links are relative?

Comment: did you have a look at the link that Sam left you above? (looks like a duplicate) since you did tag as javascript/jquery.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes , but I did not understand it . I need something similar to @ rahul answer but in PHP . like one command or loop to change all href . Thank you

Comment: so why did you add the javascript/jquery tags? you need to remove those if you're wanting a PHP solution, since that implies that you're looking for those methods. You'll need to edit your question in order to let visitors to the question know of what you want/need here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- can I use this javascript code inside the PHP and then use the result in PHP ?

Comment: see this Q&A then for PHP http://stackoverflow.com/q/6240414/ could be something in there you can use.

Comment: Simple solution that could cause issues, `str_replace('href="', 'href="http://www.example.com/', $string);` or use domdocument and pull all href attributes.

Comment: @chris85 ^^^ Let's only hope somebody doesn't come along and sweep the rug from under your feet ;-)

Comment: @MuadhProgrammer any issues with any of your answers?

Comment: @chris85 Thank you very much , your answer solved the problem. But I don't know why my question get vote down !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a simple string replace like:

```
str_replace('href="', 'href="http://www.example.com/', $string);
```

or with domdocument:

```
$page = '<html><head></head><body><a href="simple"></a><h1>Hi</h1><a href="simple2"></a></body></html>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($page);
$as = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($as as $a){
    $a->setAttribute('href', 'http://www.example.com/' . $a->getAttribute('href'));
}
print_r($doc->saveHTML());
```

output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><head></head><body><a href="http://www.example.com/simple"></a><h1>Hi</h1><a href="http://www.example.com/simple2"></a></body></html>
```

This doesn't take into account absolute paths, you'll need a regex approach for that..

If the quote types vary you also will need to use a regex for the `str_replace` example. Can do something like`('|")` for that then use `$1` to match the quote type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)** to iterate your anchor tags. Then using **[`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** you should be able to get the href attribute value.

Then a string append using `+` should do the work. So something like the below one should work

```
$("a.links").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var currentHref = $this.attr("href");
    var modifiedHref = "your string" + currentHref;

    $this.attr("href", modifiedHref);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add

```
<base href="http://localhost/"></base>
```

Inside head section. 
its create base url for all other anchor tag. will converted Url as you want.

It will work for you.
Try it.

Answer (score 0):

here is a pure javascript approach using **`replace`**

```
//replace selector 'a' with your css selector if needed
for(var i=0;i<document.querySelectorAll('a').length;++i){
var new_href=document.querySelectorAll('a')[i].getAttribute('href').replace(/(http:[/]{2}localhost)[/].*/ig, '$1/mynewpage.php')
document.querySelectorAll('a')[i].setAttribute('href',new_href)
}
//
```

Answer (score 0):

Just append "/" before your url like

```
href='oldpage.php' => href='/oldpage.php'
```